# Qt application remains in memory after closing all windows

Tags: qt, opencv

I'm a beginner in using Qt and OpenCV, and I have a small problem. 
My application works fine, but after closing it seems that opencv.exe (application name) is still in memory. 
Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("img.jpg");
    cv::namedWindow("Image");
    cv::imshow("Image",img);
    return a.exec();
}
```

How to kill task with closing application window?
I don't sure that I work correct with exec() function.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I found a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180394/how-do-i-create-a-simple-qt-console-application-in-c

Answer (score 1):

`QCoreApplication::exec()` starts an event loop.

Often times this is tied to the presence of a terminal window.

With `QApplication::exec()` it also starts an event loop, but it usually is tied to the presence of a `QMainWindow` or the last `QWidget` that was opened.

The easiest way right now for you to close it, is to go to Projects > Run > Run in Terminal, and check it.

You may also need to go to your .pro file and add `CONFIG += console`.

When you start using Qt signals and slots, the event loop will be extremely useful.

Also for any of Qt's GUIs to function properly you need the `exec()` event loop running.

Another way that you can kill your task when running it in Qt Creator is to go to the `Application Output` tab at the bottom and click the red square stop button.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call `qApp->quit()` in the close event of your non-qt window (I don't know OpenCV though).

`qApp` is equivalent to `QCoreApplication::instance()` if you started a non-gui application (in Qt terms of course), or a `QApplication` if you started a gui application.

Answer (score 0):

To gracefully come out of event loop started by `QCoreApplication::exec()` [`QCoreApplication::quit ()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#quit) must be called.
Somehow when you are done with your OpenCV stuff it should call [`QCoreApplication::quit ()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#quit). As it is a static slot you can connect a signal to it or call it explicitly.