# Why is important to include ".moc" file at end of a Qt Source code file?

Tags: c++, qt, introspection, moc

Why is it important to add an include for .moc file in a Qt cpp source code?

This is a common step used in several Qt samples, including this one:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html; where the line `#include "testqstring.moc"` should be included in the end of the file.

I don't understand exactly why this is necessary.

Comment: You don't need to do that if you declare your `Q_OBJECT` classes in a separate header file. Otherwise it's missing all the additional features that make a `QObject` a, well, `QObject`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**It's necessary if you define `QObject` subclasses with the `Q_OBJECT` macro in a `.cpp` file.** When you do so:

1. *`qmake` must generate rules inside your `Makefile` to invoke `moc` on that `.cpp` file.*

   That special (hackish?) inclusion triggers `qmake` to do so, and tells it which would be `moc`'s output file (`teststring.moc`) when invoked on your `.cpp`.
2. *In order to compile `moc`'s output (which is still a bunch of C++ code) the compiler must see your class definition.* Otherwise, it will complain that there's no such thing as `YourClass::staticMetaObject` and similar, because it has no idea that `YourClass` exists.

   Typically one defines classes featuring `Q_OBJECT` in a header file. `moc` then adds a `#include "header.h"` into its generated output, and this means `moc`'s output can be happily compiled.

   *But what if your class definition is inside a `.cpp`? You can't `#include` a `.cpp` file in `moc`'s output, as that would give you tons of redefinition errors.*

   Instead, you `#include` `moc`'s output in your `.cpp`, so that it gets compiled together and everyone is happy. (This means `qmake` will only emit one rule saying to run `moc`, but not another rule telling the compiler to compile `moc`'s output.)

From 2. you can also also desume that defining classes with `Q_OBJECT` in a `.h` does not require any special inclusion.

Comment: why does qt documentation at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html; does include a moc file in cpp ??

Comment: As I said, there's a class definition featuring a `Q_OBJECT` in a cpp.

Answer (score 5):

**Make an addition:**

When `Q_OBJECT` in xxx.h, after `qmake`, the system will generate a `moc_xxx.cpp` with xxx.h in it.

When `Q_OBJECT` in xxx.cpp, after `qmake`, the system will generate a `xxx.moc`, and you need to add the .moc file into the .cpp file.