# How to use the pimpl idiom with Qt and subclasses of QObject

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, pimpl-idiom, moc

I would like to know the easiest way to implement the pimpl idiom in Qt objects. What I want to have is something like this:

pimpl.h:

```
class B;

class A: public QObject {
    B *b;
}
```

pimpl.cxx:

```
class B: public QObject {
}
```

Now, as is obvious, Qt will not pass the class B to create the moc for it. How this can be handled? I want to have the implementation of B in the .cxx explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the Qt's PIMPL idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250171/how-to-use-the-qts-pimpl-idiom)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight As far I can see, there's no mention of the impl class itself being a `QObject` in the linked answer, so I voted to leave open.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a pimpl-private.h that contains the definition of B and is only included from pimpl.cxx, nowhere else. Then you can run moc over this header.

Comment: Yes, this is fine. However, I was looking for a hack if possible to keep it in the .cxx file as I am more used to it and do not have to fwd declare/include types there for most the part.

Comment: @code_not_yet_complete: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928933/why-is-important-to-include-moc-file-at-end-of-a-qt-source-code-file

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have the code in the .cpp file by adding

```
#inlude "pimpl.moc"
```

at the end(!) of "pimpl.cxx" and re-running qmake. This will generate a Makefiule rule to run the file through moc and put the output into a "pmipl.moc" so everything magically works.

Comment: missing "c" in include. other (less fatal) typost, too.