# How can my class inherit an interface and QObject ?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I have this interface :

```
class ISocketClient
{
public:
  ~ISocketClient() {}
  virtual bool      connectToHost(std::string const &hostname, unsigned short port) = 0;
  virtual void      closeClient() = 0;
  virtual bool      sendMessage(Message &) = 0;
  virtual Message   *getMessage() = 0;
};
```

And this is my class that inherits is:

```
class TCPClient : public  QObject, ISocketClient
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  TCPClient(QObject *parent = 0);
  ~TCPClient();
  bool connectToHost(std::string const &hostname, unsigned short port);
  void closeClient();
  bool sendMessage(Message &);
  Message *getMessage();
public slots:
  void readMessage();
private:
  QTcpSocket *tcpSocket;
};
```

But when I compile I have this error:

```
/home/danilo_d/Epitech-Projects/Semestre5/QtNetworkTest/TCPClient.cpp:4: error: undefined reference to `vtable for TCPClient'
```

And when I take out my inheritance of QObject, it works.

Have any idea how I can do that ?

Comment: Can you show the `TCPClient.cpp`?

Comment: I think you want: `class TCPClient : public  QObject, public ISocketClient`, anyway `~ISocketClient() {}` should be virtual

Comment: @user3528438 Really? That's not how I read the [Multiple Inheritance Requires QObject to Be First](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first) requirement.

Comment: @user3528438 as long as `ISocketClient` didn't inherit from `QObject`, and QObject is the first base, it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you aren't including the `.moc` file in the build. See [Qt Linker Error: "undefined reference to vtable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555816/qt-linker-error-undefined-reference-to-vtable) for a similar problem, although, provided that your build system is unknown, the idea is that:

a) you need to make sure `moc` is ran on your `.cpp` file and

b) that the resulting `.cpp` file is included in the build.

How exactly it is done, depends on the build system. For instance, in my current project, with Cmake 3.x.x, this command is enough:

```
set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set (CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
```

For GNU `make`, here is an example of how it can be done:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/moc.html#writing-make-rules-for-invoking-moc

For `qmake`, see e.g.

[Why is important to include ".moc" file at end of a Qt Source code file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928933/why-is-important-to-include-moc-file-at-end-of-a-qt-source-code-file)

As for multiple inheritance, that's not allowed if multiple `QObject`'s are to be inherited. On the contrary, when there is one `QObject` and multiple "conventional" classes, that works fine.