# GCC 5.4 compiler not recognizing included MOC files during build (Qt5, Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: c++, qt5, ubuntu-16.04, moc, boost-build

I have Qt 5.6.2 installed on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit). My project build is successful except for my compiler (GCC 5.4) giving me this error over and over again:

```
fatal error: No such file or directory
... #include "some_cpp_file.moc"
```

The **file exists** in the output directory by the time this error is thrown, and **Qt5 moc's the files with no error**. It is interesting to note that this error only happens with the source .cpp files I am moc'ing. When I explicitly specify the output directory in the build script (Jamroot), the build is successful - however, this is impractical for the amount of projects that I need to build.

This project built successfully on Ubuntu 14.04 with Qt 4.8. I have installed Qt5 from the .run file they provide and also built the binaries from scratch, but no luck. The build system I am using is **Boost.Build** (b2) which I also use on Ubuntu 14.04 with Qt4.8 with no issues, a.k.a. I use the Jamroot file to control the build and not a CMake or qmake file.

***How can I make the gcc compiler look in the output directory (bin/gcc-5.4/release/...) without explicitly telling it to look there?*** Is there some flag I need to add?

Thank you very much for your help in advance. :-)

*Note: I realize that there aren't many details about the build system or anything, but I can't share many details - I am okay with any general advice or direction if you feel this question is not detailed enough for you to solve completely!*

Comment: Why are you even including the .moc file?

Comment: Answer to that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928933/why-is-important-to-include-moc-file-at-end-of-a-qt-source-code-file) :-)

Comment: Yeah, this is why it's not a good idea to define `Q_OBJECT` classes in cpp files. I'd just stick to using .h files for that. Then you don't run into this problem (which I have no idea how to solve, since I avoid it to begin with :-P)

Comment: @NikosC. Thanks for the advice :-) I will definitely follow it in the future, unfortunately this isn't code I've written all myself so I have to solve this build problem without changing the source code (I can modify the build parameters, though).

Comment: Here's a shot in the dark: Add the build directory to the include path. Something like `INCLUDEPATH += $$OUT_PWD` in your project file.

Comment: Or `INCLUDEPATH += $$OUT_PWD/tmp` if the moc files are placed inside the tmp directory.

Comment: @NikosC. That may work - I don't know the equivalent of $$OUT_PWD in a Jamroot file though, without explicitly defining the path.