# Class inherited from QLabel, why custom slot is not called?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlabel, qt-signals

I made class inherited from `QLabel`. This class also have public slot, that should change label caption. I "call" this *SLOT* with `clicked()` *SIGNAL* of button. 
So nothing happened when I press the button.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

class Label : public QLabel
{
public:
    Label(QString a) : QLabel(a){}

public slots:
    void change()
    {
        this->setNum(2);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Button");
    Label* lbl = new Label("Label");

    button->show();
    lbl->show();

    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), lbl, SLOT(change()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

What should I do to change caption from slot?

Comment: As a general rule, do not declare `QObject` derived classes in main.cpp or if possible in any cpp, this way you have to manually include the moc files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the signals and slots to be recognized, the classes must use the [`Q_OBJECT`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) macro in the private part.

Another thing to do is to include `"main.moc"`, for more information on this point read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928933/why-is-important-to-include-moc-file-at-end-of-a-qt-source-code-file).

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

class Label : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Label(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags()) :
     QLabel(text, parent, f){}

public slots:
    void change()
    {
        setNum(2);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Button");
    Label* lbl = new Label("Label");

    button->show();
    lbl->show();

    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), lbl, SLOT(change()));

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

At the end of making these changes you must execute the following:

1. Press clean all in the Build menu.
2. then run qmake in the same menu.
3. And you just compose your project.

Comment: After adding Q_OBJECT there is an error : " undefined reference to `vtable for Label' ". And there is  "main.moc: No such file or directory"

Comment: Forgot to say that this error appears on the constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not help at all

Comment: owwww. I forgot .moc. Now it is ok

Answer (score 1):

Add `Q_OBJECT` after

```
class Label : public QLabel
{
```

and then you should

**either** place your `Label` class declaration to a `.h` file **or** write `#include "main.moc"` after `main` function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

try to get the return value from your connect call an check it for true or false. 
Add Q_OBJECT Macro to the beginning of your derived class. 
Add some debug output to your slot like

```
qDebug()<<"This is my slot.";
```

Maybe this would help to get a little further.

Best regards