# Why cannot write a QWidget class in the main.cpp?

Tags: c++, qt

**Update:**

If I delete `Q_OBJECT`, and I do not use `SLOT` `SINGAL`, just use `connect()` like this:

`connect(this, &QWidget::destroyed, this, &QWidget::myslot)`,

my code will run well without any warnings and errors.

---

I want to write a little code to instruct some classes, so I try to simplify my code. But I encountered some strange things. I cannot write a simple `widget` in my **main.cpp**. If I write the widget in `mywidget.cpp` and `mywidget.h`, the program runs well. If I want to write the widget in the `main.cpp`, what should I do?

This is my code.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
};

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And the error information is:
[image: error information]

Comment: I would say it's an issue with the MOC: it only runs on header files. But the Q_OBJECT macro needs the MOC to work. If you remove the Q_OBJECT macro, everything will be fine

Comment: Yes. remove  `Q_OBJECT`, the code runs well. But if I remove it, I cannot use the `connect()`, which is a useful function I need

Comment: Sure, I suggest you look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928933/why-is-important-to-include-moc-file-at-end-of-a-qt-source-code-file)

Comment: Declarations should be in the `.hpp` or `.h` file, not in the `.cpp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following line to the end of main.cpp and rerun `qmake`:

```
#include "main.moc"
```

That will invoke `moc` tool for your main.cpp. It generates meta-object function definitions for your `Widget` class resolving your linker errors when you rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html#usage):

> Whenever qmake is run, it parses the project's header files and
>   generates make rules to invoke moc for those files that contain a
>   Q_OBJECT macro.

Thus, put the class declaration in a header file (e.g. widget.h) and the class definition in a source file with the same name (e.g. widget.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to make it work with signals you can remove the `Q_OBJECT` macro and use the `QObject::connect()`

for example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <iostream>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    //Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
};


Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    // say bey
    QObject::connect(this,&Widget::destroyed,
                     [](){std::cout<<"bye"<<std::endl;});
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I test it on Qt5.9.4

Comment: When I delete the `QObject::`, the program runs well, too.