# No rule needed to make target .moc

Tags: c++, qt, openvpn

I am trying to turn ovpn3's ovpncli example into a class that derives from QObject. I'm unable to turn the source file into a separate interface (.h) and implementation (.cpp) file. To make the MOC happy, I've put `#include "openvpn.moc"` at the end of openvpn.cpp (the source file). I am getting this error however: `:-1: error: No rule to make target 'openvpn.moc', needed by 'openvpnmanager.o'.  Stop.` I've cleaned the build directory, re-ran qmake, and rebuilt it 1000 times. Despite this, it still refuses to work. What am I doing wrong?

myproject.pro:

```
QT       += core widgets network
CONFIG += c++11
UI_SOURCES_DIR = src/gui
UI_HEADERS_DIR = include

. . .

SOURCES += \
    src/main.cpp \
    src/gui/loginwindow.cpp \
    src/api/api.cpp \
    src/openvpn/openvpn.cpp \
    src/alert.cpp \
    src/gui/vpn.cpp \
    src/api/account.cpp \
    src/crypto.cpp \
    src/killswitch.cpp \
    src/vpnstatus.cpp \
    src/gui/logdialog.cpp \
    src/logitem.cpp \
    src/authenticationworker.cpp \
    src/api/error.cpp \
    src/openvpn/openvpnmanager.cpp \
    src/api/server.cpp \
    src/api/authenticationresponse.cpp

HEADERS += \
    include/loginwindow.h \
    include/api.h \
    include/alert.h \
    include/vpn.h \
    include/account.h \
    include/crypto.h \
    include/killswitch.h \
    include/configtype.h \
    include/vpnstatus.h \
    include/connectionstatus.h \
    include/loglevel.h \
    include/logdialog.h \
    include/logitem.h \
    include/authenticationworker.h \
    include/error.h \
    include/openvpnmanager.h \
    include/server.h \
    include/authenticationresponse.h \

FORMS += \
    src/gui/loginwindow.ui \
    src/gui/vpn.ui \
    src/gui/logdialog.ui

RESOURCES += \
    src/resources.qrc

DISTFILES +=
```

openvpn.cpp:

```
class Client : public QObject, public ClientAPI::OpenVPNClient {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    . . .
```

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

Simply delete your `build-xxx` folder, and rebuild from scratch!

#### Context

You (almost) never have to include a `.moc` file. Moc files are created automatically by the `moc`ompiler and compiled and linked in a dedicated translation unit (i.e. like any `.cpp` file).

The only exception is when your `QObject` class is declared in a `cpp` file (which happens to be your case!), because the `.moc` implementation will still require your class definition to compile. As suggested in the comments, there is a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928933/why-is-important-to-include-moc-file-at-end-of-a-qt-source-code-file).

#### Potential issues

Regarding your specific issue, `moc` file issues can originate from:

- the `Q_OBJECT` keyword is missing (but you have it). This token is used to trigger the generation of a `.moc` file for that specific class. Without it, most QObject features are missing.
- the class was parsed/compiled previously *without* the `Q_OBJECT` keyword, and cached as a non-QObject class. In that case, you just have to *manually* delete your build folder (or run `qmake` manually), to force identifying again which classes should be `moc`ed.
- You are using the wrong filename for your `moc`ed file. The correct name is typically

  - `moc_filename.cpp` when your class is declared in a header file
  - `filename.moc` when your class is declared in a source file
- `qmake` does not actually parses your `.cpp` file. This can be the case if your `.pro` file doesn't include it in the `SOURCES` variable, or if you are just never running `qmake` (specific setup, etc.)

#### Sample Makefile

You can double check it your `moc` files has appropriate rules in the Makefile of its project. Below is a sample portion of a Makefile:

```
compiler_moc_source_make_all: mysourcefile.moc

compiler_moc_source_clean:
    -$(DEL_FILE) mysourcefile.moc

mysourcefile.moc: /home/aleravat/Qt/5.9.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/QCoreApplication \
        /home/aleravat/Qt/5.9.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h \
        /home/aleravat/Qt/5.9.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h \
        /home/aleravat/Qt/5.9.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qconfig-bootstrapped.h \
        # [...] more includes
    /home/aleravat/Qt/5.9.7/gcc_64/bin/moc $(DEFINES) --include ./moc_predefs.h [...] mysourcefile.cpp -o mysourcefile.moc
```

Comment: Clarification: you must include moc in the cpp file manually if you place QObject derived class into a cpp file. See good explanation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928933/why-is-important-to-include-moc-file-at-end-of-a-qt-source-code-file)

Comment: Oh thanks! I actually didn't see that the OP had his class definition in a `.cpp` file. That was the reason of my "(almost) never", but I guess it totally makes sense to explain it now.

Comment: I'm looking at my Makefile generated by Qt's qmake and there is no moc_openvpn.cpp anywhere. In the 3rd bulletpoint are you suggesting that openvpn.cpp must be renamed?

Comment: You're defining your class in a cpp file, so your original name is probably the right one, `openvpn.moc`. Do you see any reference to that particular one or any variation around `openvpn`? Are you sure that your file is listed in the `SOURCES` variable of your `.pro` as well?

Comment: These two files are included in my Makefile under openvpnmanager.o (openvpnmanager.cpp includes openvpn.cpp):  `src/openvpn/openvpn.cpp \
                openvpn.moc \ `

Comment: Ok so you have something missing. Did you check the SOURCES variable in your .pro? Or do you call `qmake` manually and pass it that specific .cpp?

Comment: My openvpn.cpp file included in the SOURCES variable as indicated by the .pro file I posted.

Comment: Mhh.. you've got an extraneous \ at the end of your header list also, you probably want to fix that. Can you share your makefile?

Comment: `openvpn.cpp` is not in the SOURCES in your makefile, only mentioned in `openvpnmanager.o`. So either you are not qmaking the right file, or this is a different Makefile

Comment: @AdrienLeravat How would I go about fixing this? This is the command used by Qt: `qmake myproject.pro -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug && /usr/bin/make qmake_all`. Before I tried making the Client class a QObject, compilation worked fine with the exact same .pro file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190883/discussion-between-adrien-leravat-and-chase).