# Custom plugin for qt is not loaded. How to debug?

Tags: qt, qt5, can-bus, socketcan, qtplugin

I wrote a custom plugin for `QCanBus`, that simply is a copy of the socketcan plugin but has been renamed and the identifiers have been adjusted to that new name.

I did that copying to first get the plugin recognised before I alter it.

I changed the qmake project to look that way:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = qtcopysocketcanbus
CONFIG += plugin
QT = core serialbus

HEADERS += \
    copysocketcanbackend.h

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    copysocketcanbackend.cpp

DISTFILES = plugin.json
```

and added the `plugin.json` like so:

```
{
    "Key": "copysocketcan"
}
```

I then renamed everything else from `socketcan` to `copysocketcan` in the `main.cpp`, the `copysocketcan.cpp` and the `copysocketcan.h` as well.

When I build the project, I get my *.so file which i put into `$QT_PLUGIN_PATH/canbus/` on my target.

However, a quick start reveals, that qt only lists the plugins that came with the installation, not my added custom one.

I tried putting `QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules(QStringLiteral("qt.canbus* = true"));` as first line in my code and hoped getting more debug output, but I only get the debug output that my own application is producing. No output from the actual `QCanBus`.

So my questions are

1. How to enable the debug output for `qt.canbus`? Do I have to build QT with debug config for that?
2. Does my approach for creating a plugin reasonable?
3. Any ideas, why the custom plugin is not listed?

Comment: Enable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` and double check the paths the other plugins are loaded from. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-plugins.html end of page

Comment: Thanks for that helpul comment. The debugging advice with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` was the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through a helpful comment, I was able to debug the problems. The commentor suggested to use `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` to debug the plugin call. That lead to the appearance of an error message, that clearly stated, that the plugin I was trying to load because it was *not a plugin* and *plugin metadata could not be extracted*.

A bit of googling after those messages helped.

The answer to question 1 is:

Yes, you apparently have QT to build with debug information, to get the actual log output.
In my case, I configured the framework with `--force-debug-info`

For the second question, my approach was indeed reasonable, because as answer for question 3 turned out that one has to include the `moc` file as soon, as a `Q_OBJECT` macro is used within a `*.cpp` file and not in a separate header, which is the case for the canbus plugins. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928933/why-is-important-to-include-moc-file-at-end-of-a-qt-source-code-file)