# Qt Creator on Ubuntu 16.04 Bugs

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator, ubuntu-16.04

I've a problem with Qt Creator. Tried to use older versions but there's the same result. now on 4.2.0 and Qt 5.7.1 and 5.8.0 installed. When I start a project (no matter what kind exactly) then there's such kind of a bugs:

First:

right click -> add new (or existing) file -> add or cancel

right click -> AND!!! now "add new" and others "adds" are grayed.

BUT after a restart it starts from the beginning. So to add each new file to project I need to restart Qt Creator...

Second:

When I'm trying to use C++  lib - and i write like this

```
std::fstream myfstr("./myfile.txt", std::ios_base::out);

myfstr<<"hi";

myfstr.close;
```

the file is beeing created in my user's HOME folder but not near the project's runfile

Third:

I can't enable the console window((

I'm really sorry for these maybe stupid questions, but I really spent much time trying to solve them.

Thanks a lot for any help!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180394/how-do-i-create-a-simple-qt-console-application-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886105/how-to-print-to-console-when-using-qt

Comment: there must be three separate questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why should `"./myfile.txt"` be located near anything specific? Check the run configuration's working directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!